# Checking to See which of the three conditions in the If Statement was True in Else If, if one was not?

Tags: java, if-statement

Assumptions: 1 of 3 of the conditions will be 0.

If I have an if statement defined as follows:

```
   if ((condition1 == 0) || condition2 == 0) || condition3 == 0)) {
     do something 
   }
```

and 3 following else if statements:

```
else if (condition1 != 0) {
  do something
  print which of condition 2 or 3 was 0
}

else if (condition2 != 0) {
  do something
  print which of condition 1 or 3 was 0
}

else if (condition3 != 0) {
  do something
  print which of condition 1 or 2 was 0
}
```

I was thinking perhaps putting nested if statements in the first if statement to see which of the three was 0.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: Yes go for it if you want to know which condition is true.

Comment: @MarounMaroun the question is, how can I figure out which of the 2 was 0 if one of them is not?

Comment: @SMA do you think I'd have to store that information (which is 0) outside of the method all these if statements are in if I will be calling on that information elsewhere?

Comment: @a44d I would just use it in while logging to be very precise.

Answer (score 0):

Came up with something. What terrible practice it is to be using this many if statements though. (assume `memorizeCondition` is stored outside the method of ifs)

```
if (condition1=0 || condition2 = 0 || condition3 = 0)
    if(condition1 = 0)
        memorizeCondition = condition1;
    if(condition2 = 0)
        memorizeCondition = condition2;
    if(condition3 = 0)
        memorizeCondition = condition3;
else if (condition1 != 0)
    memorizeCondition;
    calculate condition1;
    calculate other condition;
else if (condition2 != 0)
    memorizeCondition;
    calculate condition2;
    calculate other condition;
else if (condition3 != 0)
    memorizeCondition;
    calculate condition2;
    calculate other condition;
```

Answer (score 0):

what about this:

```
    if ((condition1 == 0) || condition2 == 0) || condition3 == 0)) {
      do something 
    } else {
      if (condition1 != 0) {
        do something
        print which of condition 2 or 3 was 0
      }
      if (condition2 != 0) {
        do something
        print which of condition 1 or 3 was 0
      }
      if (condition3 != 0) {
        do something
        print which of condition 1 or 2 was 0
      }
    }
```

If there are a lot more than 3 conditions you can add them to a collection and then use stream.filter() to remove all non matching conditions.